# Change Header Font in MS Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

Since MS Dynamics CRM 2013 is rather new, I haven't been able to find any answers on this.  Hopefully someone here has discovered how to do this.

I'm wanting to change the look of the Header Tiles on a MS Dynamics CRM 2013 form.  I'd love to make the tiles wider, but I don't think that's an option.  What I'd at least like to do is make the field font smaller so more info fits on each tile.

Can anyone shed some light on this?  I can't find any CSS or Xrm.Page.??? reference to that object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Before I point out the .css which needs to be modified, this is unsupported and at your own risk! Any future rollups might break this or cause issues.

Since you're speaking of tiles, I believe you're referring to 'Account', 'Contact', 'Leads', etc.

To change the font size, you need to manually edit a file from where Dynamics CRM 2013 is installed. The path is : `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\CRMWeb\_controls\navbar` and the file name is `navbar.css.aspx`.

You need to change the font size for the following css class:

```
.navActionButtonLabel
{
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
font-size: 9.75pt;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Change the font-size property, save it and give an IISRESET, and it should work. Always remember to take a backup in case anything goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is older, but I found this issue still persists in Dynamics CRM 2015, so I created this function and added the "LoadChangeHeaderTiles" function to the forms "OnLoad" event:

```
function LoadChangeHeaderTiles() {
   changeHeaderTileFormat();
   setInterval(changeHeaderTileFormat, 1000);
}

function changeHeaderTileFormat() {
   var headertiles = document.getElementsByClassName("ms-crm-HeaderTileElement");
   if (headertiles != null) {
      for (var i = 0; i < headertiles.length; i++) {
         headertiles[i].style.width = "175px"; 
      }
   }
}
```

I know DOM manipulations are unsupported still, but since none of the original CRM files are being modified, you can always remove this code from the onload event later and no harm will be done.